# ob->i supposed to return the adress of ob "this" but it returns i ,any explanation?

Tags: c++, overloading

`ob->i` is supposed to return the address of ob `this` but it returns `i`, any explanation?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myclass {
public:
  int i; 

  myclass *operator->() {return this;}
};

int main() {
  myclass ob;
  ob.i = 10; 

  cout << ob.i << " " << ob->i;
  // ob->i supposed to return the address of ob "this" but it returns i 

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `operator->` is a bit tricky. When the compiler sees an expression like your `ob->i` it first applies `myclass::operator->()`, as you'd expect. But that doesn't deal with the `i` part that comes after the `->`, so the compiler then applies the `->` operator to whatever the call to `myclass::operator->()` returned. It keeps doing that until it gets a plain old pointer, and then it knows how to deal with the `i`. So in the code above, there are two steps for `ob->i`. First, it calls `myclass::operator->()` and gets back `this`, whose type is `myclass*`. Now it's got a plain pointer, so it uses that pointer to get to the `i` that belongs to `ob`.

This makes it possible to write classes that look like ordinary pointers:

```
struct my_type {
    int i;
};

class funky_class {
    my_type* operator->() { return &obj; }
private:
    my_type obj;
};
```

Now I can say

```
funky_class funky;
funky->i = 3;
```

The last line changes the value of the `i` inside `funky.obj`.

In the real world that example is kind of silly; instead, `funky_class` would hold a pointer to some other object. That's why you can write

```
std::shared_ptr<my_type> my_obj(new my_type);
my_obj->i = 3;
```

Here, `my_obj::operator->` returns a `my_type*`, and the compiler uses that pointer to get at the `i` member of `my_type`.

Answer (score 4):

The returning of `i` makes sense here. Your call is equivalent to saying `this->i` since `this` is what your arrow operator returns. In other words, you are dereferencing `this`, and using it to access the variable `i` in your class. To get the address of your object, you have to use the unary `&` (reference) operator on the object, i.e (`std::cout << &obj << "\n"`)

Comment: but the overloading of the arrow (->) operator makes it  returns the adress of the object here  (it returns this )

Comment: Right, the function gets called, and this and the second argument are evaluated, resulting in 10. (@PeteBecker explains this better than I do...)